# Probability of Particular Sequence

Tags: probability

I am currently thinking about a problem involving a biased coin, which is tossed seven times. I am asked to find the probability of getting the sequence HHHHTTT in that *particular* order.

I am confused as to wether I should solve this problem using a permutation or binomial distribution. Does order matter with a binomial distribution or not? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Binomial will give you the probability of 4 heads out of 7, ignoring order. Why not go back to basics and think about the probability of Heads and Heads and ... combined with independence?

Comment: @Paul If every toss is independent, then that's where I think that the binomial distribution could make sense. But if sequence matters, then I am thinking permutation. I am confused because similiar problems online use the binomial distribution and I just don't understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ X = (X_1, ..., X_7) $ be a random variable, where the $X_i$ are identical distributed and independent, with $ \mathbb{P}(X_1 = H) = p$ and $ \mathbb{P}(X_1 = T) = 1 - p$. So the probability of your sequence of particular order is
$$\mathbb{P}(X = (H,H,H,H,T,T,T)) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = H, ..., X_7 = T) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = H) \cdot ... \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_7 = T) = p⁴\cdot(1-p)³$$

Now a Binomial distribution multiplies this with the number of all sequences with the same amount of Heads and Tails. So a Binomial distribution does not consider a sequence in a particular order. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for this. The distribution you provided is a Bernoulli distribution, right? Since this is an unfair coin, I don't know how to assign p. Usually I would just assign it as 0.5 since there is a 50/50 chance of getting H or T.